# Dynamically draw outline oval over a view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I am working with a custom UI element highlights.So I need to draw a half ellipse like shape over a particular view on runtime.

For example:
I have to draw a yellow color half ellipse over a white ellipse.

[image: Like this]

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: canvas can be used to draw this.have you tried anything ?

Comment: @santosh Can you help me how to move forward in this direction ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float width = (float) getWidth();
        float height = (float) getHeight();
        float radius;

        if (width > height) {
         radius = height / 4;
        } else {
         radius = width / 4;
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(width / 2,
         height / 2, radius,
         Path.Direction.CW);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float center_x, center_y;
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        center_x = width / 2;
        center_y = height / 2;

        oval.set(center_x - radius,
            center_y - radius,
            center_x + radius,
            center_y + radius);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 180, false, paint);
    }
}
```

Add

```
new MyView(this)
```

Comment: Outlined view is exactly not a circle and I want it drawn on the boundary of view.